# What would be the result of the following assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following IA-32 assembly code, and I want to know what the values on V will look like.
For simplicity, the start address of V is considered to be 0x0, with a *little-endian* structure.

```
.data
V: .byte 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
.text
_start:  mov $2,%eax
         mov %eax,(V)
         mov $V,%eax
         add $4, %eax
         mov %eax, (%eax)
```

As I see it, I should have on output `V = 2,1,1,1,4,1,1,1,1`, but I have also been told that the output should be something like `V = 2,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,1`. I cannot comprehend why the bytes' value between the first and the fourth byte would be null, and why only the 9th byte would remain with the pre-run value.

Comment: Try running the code in a debugger like `gdb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause `eax` is a 32-bit register, you are writing a 32-bit value (4 bytes) to `V` using

```
mov %eax,(V)
```

Even if 2 fits into one byte, there are always 4 bytes written. Using

```
mov $2,%eax
```

the upper bits of `eax` are set to zero. The register `al` contains the lower 8 bits of `eax`. So if you only want a 8-bit value (1 byte) to be written, better use

```
mov %al,(V)
```

Comment: I had completely forgotten that the size of the moved register mattered. That's why it rewrites 3 unwanted bytes of V. Thanks so much!